# R - confused about the axis scaling

Tags: r, plot, axis

```
data = read.table("Þjóðin_Kyn.txt",
+                   fill=TRUE,sep="\t",
+                   header=TRUE
+                   )
> plot(data[(1:10),10],
+      data[(1:10),3],
+      type="o",
+      main="Þjóð - Kyn",
+      xlab="Ár",
+      ylab="Aldrei (%)",
+      xaxp=c(2005,2014,9),
+      yaxp=c(0,100,50),
+      ylim=c(0,100))
> print( data[(1:10),10] )
 [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
[10] 2014
> print( data[(1:10),3] )
 [1] 78%    80.90% 82.90% 83.10% 91.40% 89%   
 [7] 82%    91%    91%    90%   
18 Levels: 67.30% 70% 71.40% 71.70% 72% ... 91.40%
```

This is my code when executed. And this is the plot produced:

[image: plot]

Why does the y value only range from 8 to 20 when the print command shows percentages in the 80-90 range?

Comment: Because that column is a factor, which is stored as integer codes with labels. You will need to go back to your data import step and import the data in the format you want. That might involve removing the percent signs using `gsub` and then coercing to character and then to numeric.